# why to state CLASSPATH option explicitly while path can be deduced from the class file

Tags: java, classpath

I know why CLASSPATH has to be provided for `java` command (and many good answers are given in SO). But I am always confused, why by default it is not deduced from the .class file path given as an argument.

e.g. (It is a silly example...)
Assume **I am in `/home`** and there is `./class/SomeClass.class` file in it.

```
/home
 |_class
   |_SomeClass.class
```

If I run `java -cp /home/class/ SomeClass` the program (SomeClass) runs successfully.

But without the `-cp` option (but with complete path) running

`java ./class/SomeClass`

throws an exception `(java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError)` saying `Could not find the main class...`.

And this means, (unless I am in the same directory) the JVM couldn't know where to find SomeClass.class file even if I explicitly stated to look it inside `./class/` directory (by prefixing it before SomeClass).

In such cases I feel the default behavior should be to consider the CLASSPATH the same directory where the .class file exists - by calculating from the path.

Is there any good reason to always use `-cp`?

Comment: Do you really throw .java files in the mix or do you mean ".class" file where you say ".java file"?

Comment: Try your sample again with packages. It's not common to have no packages.

Comment: @puce I edited my question... but I know a very silly example. I just want to make my point

Comment: again: try to rephrase your question using packages. Maybe things get more clear on the way.